# Segmentation fault error on importing from old cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

**Describe the bug**

I have 3 existing Redis nodes sharded by application (IBM Infosphere Streams DPS Toolkit). Now I have created a new v6.2.4 cluster and trying to import data from old nodes but keep on getting error Segmentation fault. Am I missing something?

```
[root@strmrd01 bin]#  ./redis-cli --cluster import 10.162.53.247:7000 --cluster-from 10.162.53.248:6380 --cluster-replace --cluster-copy
>>> Importing data from 10.162.53.248:6380 to cluster 10.162.53.247:7000
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 10.162.53.247:7000)
M: 1d0561ac912a8d9f6a35a98a9eda37715a69e51a 10.162.53.247:7000
   slots:[0-5460] (5461 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: ae9e6759aeb60e0eb4730014673a9a91f80d6b76 10.162.53.248:7001
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 79fb0a114ed2e2ce22a573c7bc87e5186795836c
S: d4edcf68fbf4b695eec42106f7bee9d683531b91 10.162.53.248:7002
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 1d0561ac912a8d9f6a35a98a9eda37715a69e51a
M: 6d49cb6f53c4dab4b874dd23d0005048b1052268 10.162.53.247:7002
   slots:[5461-10922] (5462 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: 60fd992708f5cc6bbd5cd433328aa836c3d2656d 10.162.53.248:7000
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 6d49cb6f53c4dab4b874dd23d0005048b1052268
M: 79fb0a114ed2e2ce22a573c7bc87e5186795836c 10.162.53.247:7001
   slots:[10923-16383] (5461 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
*** Importing 33350 keys from DB 0
Segmentation fault
[root@avqa-strmrd01 bin]# pwd
/app/redis6.2.4/bin
[root@strmrd01 bin]#
```